# Pointer-to-member function with pre-defined arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Looking to pass a pointer-to-member function with pre-defined arguments into a function.

```
typedef void(ClassWithFunction::*Func)(int, int);

m_cwf = ClassWithFunction(); // member variable

int arg1 = 0;
int arg2 = 1;

giveMeAFunction(&ClassWithFunction::aFunc);
```

Using `std::bind` it is possible to pre-define what arguments an `std::function` will use.

```
giveMeAFunction(std::bind(&ClassWithFunction::aFunc, &m_cwf, arg1, arg2));
```

How can I do this using C-style function pointers?

```
void ClassProcessingFunction::giveMeAFunction(Func func)
{
    func(); // arguments pre-applied
}
```

Comment: You can't. That's why std::bind exists.